# CSS3 animation-delay Property Not Working

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rollover Test</title>
    <style>
    #one {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: red;
        position: absolute;
        left: 1110px; 
        top: 110px;
        opacity: 1;
        animation: myfirst 5s;
        -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s;
    }

    @keyframes myfirst
    {
        from {opacity: 0; width: 50px; height: 0px;}
        to {opacity: 1; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes myfirst
    {
        from {opacity: 0; width: 50px; height: 0px;}
        to {opacity: 1; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
    }

    #two {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: red;
        position: absolute;
        left: 1110px; 
        top: 200px;
        opacity: 1;
        animation: mysecond 5s;
        animation-delay: 5s;
        -webkit-animation: mysecond 5s;
        -webkit=animation-delay: 5s;
    }

    @keyframes mysecond
    {
        from {opacity: 0; width: 50px; height: 0px;}
        to {opacity: 1; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes mysecond
    {
        from {opacity: 0; width: 50px; height: 0px;}
        to {opacity: 1; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div id="one"></div>

<div id="two"></div>

<div id="three"></div>

<div id="four"></div>

<div id="five"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

I cannot get `mysecond` to wait 5 seconds before playing on `two`, using `animation-delay`. I basically want it to be that `myfirst` plays, then after it is done, `mysecond` plays. I have experimented with the order of the `animation: mysecond 5s;` and `animation-delay: 5s;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo there:

```
-webkit=animation-delay
//     ^
```

So the `-webkit-animation` shorthand property is overriding the `animation-delay` declared before that.

Fix the typo, and you'll have `-webkit-animation-delay` declared after `-webkit-animation`.

Comment: Thanks, but now only ``myfirst`` plays.

Comment: @Mr.Shtuffs - Wait 5 seconds, and it'll run. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xj6s2/

Comment: Oh, I see, but the problem is that I want ``two`` to disappear before it plays.

Comment: But, then I want it to stay at 1 afterwards.

Comment: @Mr.Shtuffs - Then leave it as 1, remove the delay, set the speed to `10s`, and add another keyframe: http://jsfiddle.net/Xj6s2/2/